# How can I display a list of blade.php files but omit the extensions?

Tags: php, laravel, file, foreach, laravel-blade

I am trying to echo out a list of files within a folder. An example filename is `example.blade.php`.

I am retrieving the files via

```php
$files = File::allFiles('path/to/my/files');
```

I loop through the array

```php
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $filename = explode('.', $file->getFilenameWithoutExtension());

    var_dump($filename);
}
```

Which returns

```sh
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "introduction"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "blade"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "test"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "blade"
}
```

I know I only need the `0` result as this is the filename in question.

I put the result in a variable and add it to the `view` data in the controller, so it can be used in Blade. When I try to generate a list in Blade

```
@foreach($filenames as $filename) {
    {{ $filename }}
@endforeach
```

I can only get the last result.

I just can't seem to put the pieces together on this so any assistance would be greatly appreciated and would let me progress

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply updating single variable which is storing one value at a time and always replaced by next one, so at the end it would contain name of the last file. Assign each file name to array using `[]`.

```
$filenames = [];
$files = File::allFiles('path/to/my/files');

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $filename = explode('.', $file->getFilenameWithoutExtension());
    $filenames[] = $filename[0];  // as you don't want blade or further extensions. 
}

return view('abc', ['filenames' => $filenames]);
```

Now you can use it in your view in similar way you've mentioned.

```
@foreach($filenames as $filename) {
    {{ $filename }}
@endforeach
```